# why jcenter is missing javers versions?

Tags: gradle, jcenter, maven-central, javers

I'm using jcenter to resolve my dependencies in Gradle projects, I migrated from mavencentral to jcenter repositories but I noticed that there are missing versions of javers in jcenter.

for example: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/javers/javers-persistence-mongo/

and: https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/javers/javers-persistence-mongo/

I was using 3.0.0 but it's missing in jcenter.
Any clue? I thought that jcenter includes mavencentral ...

Comment: from jcenter we probably sync to maven center. may be last two version is not synced.

Comment: RegRog thanks for pointing this problem. Looks like there is a problem in javers bintray repository linking to jcentral. Some artifacts are promoted properly, for example https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/javers/javers-core/ I will try to contact jfrog team to fox this. Meanwhile you can use Maven Central

Comment: I see someone is working on it, but now javers-core is messed up, maven-metadata.xml file doesn't match with available versions. https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/javers/javers-core/

Comment: https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/503

Comment: yep, that's me. I thought the problem was considered solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, jfrog bintray team didn't resolve this issue for seven days since reporting. They don't have any SLA in this case and they can't say when JCenter sync will be fixed for JaVers repository.

Publishing to JCenter seems now pointless to me.
Starting from 3.0.2, JaVers artifacts will be published only to Maven Central

Comment: I'm not happy about this ...
It means that I can not use jcenter any more

Comment: bintray claims thay JCenter mirrors Maven Central, see https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-should-i-use-jcenter-over-maven-central/ 
So maybe if they fix the issue with javers repository sync, our artifacts would appear there. But the source of truth for JaVers is now Maven Central

Comment: Yeah they claim that but in the end I can not trust jcenter at 100%. Thanks for your help.